# Error: argument

Tags: shiny, shiny-server

I'm trying to create a histogram of density and I'm having the error: argument 'x' must be numeric. I tried to use (as.numeric(input$d)) instead of just d but got the same error. Does anyone know how to solve this?

server.R

```R
output$hist <- renderPlot({

  input$action

  if(is.null(input$action))
    return(NULL)

  else

    isolate({

      trees3 <- FindTreesCHM(chm(), (as.numeric(input$fws)), (as.numeric(input$minht)))
      d <- density(trees3["height"])
      plot(d, xlab = "Height", ylab = "Density", main = "")
      polygon((as.numeric(input$d)), col = "darkseagreen")

    })
  })
```

Thank you a lot! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the problem is in `d <- density(trees3["height"])`. The first argument of the `density` function is `x` and it should be numeric. You are using `[]` instead of `[[]]`. `[]` return the list of elements and `[[]]` return the single element on the list. So just try changing

`d <- density(trees3["height"])`

with

`d <- density(trees3[["height"]])`.

Also, I don't think you need the `else` in your code. But if you need to use an `if...else` statement make sure that:

> It is important to note that **else** must be in the same line as the closing braces of the if statements. http://www.programiz.com/r-programming/if-else-statement

Comment: Hey Geovany! I totally see your point and it worked well man! I really appreciate your help. But here's a doubt. When you say hat using [[ ]] returns the single element on the list you mean one value from the column? Cause I'd like to capture the entire column to plot. I'm sorry about my confusion. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad to know that it help you. The single element in the list, so it could one value, a vector, or any other structure stored in the list. In this case it will be the entire column. You can get access to individual values by `[["heigh"]][n]`

Comment: Oh, I got it Geovany! Thanks so much for your help and explanation! :)